# Is Armenia the first Christian state?

Tags: religion, christianity, date, armenia

I have heard from people and read on the internet that Armenia is considered to be the first country to adopt Christianity as state religion (the exact date is widely disputed, though 301 AD is the traditional date).

**How well-established is this whole claim among modern historians?**

I am interested in the core claim, the exact date of conversion does not matter to me, though it would be nice if the answer included information about the date too.

I can't find any definitive answer on the current state of this claim among modern historians, which is why I'm asking this question here on History SE.

Comment: WIkipedia actually has a list from where we can pick some sources and search further : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_official_adoptions_of_Christianity

Answer (score 7):

## The ancient state of Osroene did it earlier

Regardless of the validity of the claim that Armenia became Christian in 301 AD, it isn't the first. Osroene - at the time a client state of the Roman Empire - formally adopted Christianity as the state religion under Abgar the Great in 201 AD.

> [Looking first to the eastward, we find that in Edessa, the capital of Osroene, the Church first ascended a throne.](https://books.google.com/books?id=32YAAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=A+History+of+the+Christian+Church+During+the+First+Six+Centuries.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXw7yO6qvbAhWKylMKHQU_C9IQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Osroene&f=false)
>
> --*Samuel Cheetham, A History of the Christian Church During the First Six Centuries, page 58*

This source is from 1905; there is another book from 1988 listed as a source on Wikipedia but Google Books doesn't have that page.

Comment: From the countless pages on the web I've been to (inlcuding many peer-reviewed scholarly encyclopedias), only Wikipedia mentioned Osroene. See, e.g., [this Britannica page](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Armenian-Apostolic-Church).

Comment: @vomadaxela It's not "just Wikipedia", the article cites two sources, one of which I linked. Maybe Britannica doesn't consider Osroene a country, who knows.

Comment: Anyway, my question is about the consensus among modern historians. The article does cite two (and only two) sources, while the Armenian claim can be found in nearly every history book on this subject. Unfortunately, your answer does not address my question, but only mentions one marginal opinion.

Comment: @Spencer If it adopted Christianity in 201, that would be before Rome's annexation in 216

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osroene) calls this an "apocryphal legend".

Comment: @Spencer IKR, I can't believe this "answer" has three upvotes now... Such things should be unacceptable on a serious site like this.

Comment: @vomadaxela Tracing the sources, it looks as if most of this can be traced back to Eusebius -- King Abgar VIII or IX supposedly converted to Christiabity just before the Empire under Julian swallowed his kingdon up. sPavel's cited source, Cheetham, in the very next sentencs after the quote, called one of Eusebius's other claims (Abgar V supposedly wrote to Jesus and received a reply) a "forgery"

Comment: [be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Other debatable candidates for "first christian state" are Silures (http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/KingListsBritain/BritainSilures.htm - uncertainty about the conversion(?) of the king(?)), San Marino (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marino#History - uncertainty about since when it can be dubbed a "state"), Aksum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezana_of_Axum - better documented, but would postdate Armenia by a few decades in Armenia's date of 301 is correct), Caucasian Albania (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urnayr) or Kartil (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartli)